# Setting the_geom to coordinate system EPSG5514 in CARTO?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, carto, epsg

How can I set my geometry column to coordinate system EPSG5514 Krovak in CARTO? I would like to publish maps on this system.

---

If I enter:

```
UPDATE
   komunikace_jtsk
SET
   the_geom = ST_Transform (ST_SetSRID (the_geom, 5514), 4326);
```

So the data will be displayed outside of the Czech Republic somewhere on the North Pole.
Also the data in the_geom layer contains geographic coordinates and not equal - EPSG5514.
the_geom:

```
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[24.83035935,59.75626015],[24.83035935,59.75626015],[24.83035935,59.75626015],[24.83035935,59.75626015],[24.83035935,59.75626015]]]]}
```

Comment: Can you share the link to your original dataset? Also, CARTO does not allow todo change basemap projection. However, here is a workaround: removing the basemap and adding a layer as a basemap.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `the_geom` column using PostGIS [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) and [ST_SetSRID](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) functions:

```
UPDATE 
  table
SET
  the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSrid(the_geom),5514),4326)
```

The following screenshot shows how to do a simple `SELECT` statement:

[image]

Do notice that I am transforming the point into web Mercator projection because I wanted only to see it.